# How to find solution

Tags: sql, laravel, database, datatable, laravel-10

```php
$annuncement_list = DB::table('ld_app_announcements')
            )
            ->join('ld_apps', ' ld_apps.id', '=', 'ld_app_announcements.ld_app_id')
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($annuncement_list)
            {
                $btn = '';
                $btn .= '<a href="javascript:void(0)"  data-app_id = "'.$annuncement_list['id'].'" data-original-title="Edit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm edit_app">
                Edit
                </a><br> &nbsp';

                $btn .='<a href="javascript:void(0)"  data-app_id = "'.$annuncement_list['id'].'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm edit_app">
                Delete
                </a> &nbsp';
                return $btn;
            })

            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
```

> Method Yajra\DataTables\QueryDataTable::join does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create query first and add the query into Yajra\DataTables\DataTables

```
    $query=DB::table('ld_app_announcements')
     ->join('ld_apps', ' ld_apps.id', '=', 'ld_app_announcements.ld_app_id');
    $annuncement_list = DataTables::of($query)
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->addColumn('action', function($annuncement_list)
        {
            $btn = '';
            $btn .= '<a href="javascript:void(0)"  data-app_id = "'.$annuncement_list->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm edit_app">
            Edit
            </a><br> &nbsp';
            $btn .='<a href="javascript:void(0)"  data-app_id = "'.$annuncement_list->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm edit_app">
            Delete
            </a> &nbsp';
            return $btn;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->make(true);
```